# Creating a Box out of '=' and '#' around the text

Tags: python, user-interface, formatting

i'm trying to create a box like this

```
==========
Example  #
Example2 #
==========
```

This is my broken code, only the 'def' parts and things after the '######' are important here.
I wanted to create a code that reads the max length of a line in the file and adds the appropriate amount of spaces in each line and a # at the end of it so it creates a box, but I failed miserably.
This is my code, please help me fix it. *The 'liner' is outdated, in the fututre it should adjust its length.*

```
import sys

def divide_chunks(l, n): 
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n]

def spacer(s):
    for nSpace in range(s):
        print('')

def devider(d):
    devide = " "
    print(devide*d)

def liner():
    print("=============================================================")

namesList = ['LIBERALIZM               ', 'KONSERWATYZM             ', 'SOCJALDEMOKRACJA         ', 'CHRZESCIJANSKA DEMOKRACJA']
shopList = []
conShopList = []
maxLengthList = 12

while len(shopList) < maxLengthList:
    item = input("Podaj odpowiedz z grupy A: ")
    shopList.append(item)
    print (shopList)

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

liner()
spacer(1)

print ("Oto twoja lista odpowiedzi grupy A:")
print (shopList)

for objShopList in shopList:
    conShopList.append(chr(ord(objShopList)+12))
#    print (conShopList)

spacer(1)

print ("Oto twoja lista odpowiedzi grupy B:")
print (conShopList)

spacer(1)
liner()
spacer(1)

print ("Oto Odpowiedzi Do Grupy A:")
for subLists in (list(divide_chunks(shopList, 3))):
        print(str(namesList[list(divide_chunks(shopList, 3)).index(subLists)]) + ' ' + str(subLists))

spacer(1)

print ("Oto Odpowiedzi Do Grupy B:")
for subLists in (list(divide_chunks(conShopList, 3))):
        print(str(namesList[list(divide_chunks(conShopList, 3)).index(subLists)]) + ' ' + str(subLists))

spacer(1)
liner()
spacer(1)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()

#########

with open('out.txt', "r+") as infile:
    chars = 0
    charsList = []
    for line in infile:
        chars = (len(line) - 1)
        charsList.append(chars)
    print(charsList)

    charsListMax = max(charsList)

    old = infile.read()
    allLines = infile.readlines()
    for nLine in range(len(allLines)):
        infile.seek(nline)
        charPos = charsListMax - (len(allLines[nLine]))
        perLineDevides = devider(charPos)
        infile.write(old + str(perLineDevides) + "#")
        print(old + str(perLineDevides) + "#")
```

I know this is super wrong and messy but my knowlage is super limited :)

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Why are you calling `infile.readlines()` immediately after `infile.read()`? If you want to iterate over lines with the line number, just use `for idx, line in enumerate(in_file):`. Why redirect `sys.stdout` to a file? You should use a context manager for that first file, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.format` to make your border.

For example:

```
lines = 'Example', 'Example2'

def make_border(lines):
    max_len = len(max(lines, key=len, default=''))
    return '='*(max_len+2) + '\n' + '\n'.join('{:<{width}}#'.format(l, width=max_len+1) for l in lines) + '\n' + '='*(max_len+2)

print(make_border(lines))
```

Prints:

```
==========
Example  #
Example2 #
==========
```

---

Or reading from file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    print(make_border(list(map(str.strip, f_in))))
```